# Mongo aggregator query: get list of documents depending on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working with 1.000 documets in a collection in MongoDb. Each document can be made of many topics, and a topic can be made of many keywords.

The mongo structure for each document is the following:

```
_id:ObjectId(6d5fc0922982bb550e08502d), 
id_doc:"1234-678-436-42"
topic:Array
keywords:Array
```

The key **topic** is an array of objects o this type

```
type:"topic"
label:"work"
```

While, the **keywords** key is an array of objects, very similar to "topic":

```
type:"keyword"
value:"programmer"
label:"work"
```

Label represents in both cases the topic of the doc!

What I want is to list all the documents (id_doc) where a topic appears in the "topic" array, but never in the "keyword" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- takes the intersection of `topic.label` with `keywords.label`
- if empty then no common members, so document passes the filter

*not sure if you want this, if not if you can give 1-2 documents in json text, and the expected output

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62d58afbbefa88fe45d75ecc)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$eq": 
       [{"$setIntersection": ["$topic.label", "$keywords.label"]}, []]}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `$filter`:

1. count the number of items in `topic` which their `label` is not present in as a `value` of an item on `keywords`. Save this count as `condMatch`
2. `$match` only document with `condMatch` greater than 0

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {condMatch: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$topic",
            cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$this.label", "$keywords.value"]}}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {condMatch: {$gt: 0}}},
  {$unset: "condMatch"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q5LYp25V0Vs)

Comment: I get this error: "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"

Comment: Did you look at the playground example? Is your structure similar to it? Is `keywords` look the same?

Comment: @nimrodserok i guess some arrays are missing from schema. In mongodb `$size` costs O(n) i didnt know it, i asked some mongodb people in past, so i think to check if empty array is better to `$eq` with [] (i think its faster)

Comment: Thanks @Takis, interesting point. I upvoted it.